# He/him and I/me: How to use personal pronouns?

Tags: word-choice, personal-pronouns, subject-vs-object-pronouns

I have a problem sometimes to determine when to use these pronouns.

I have read other articles before on this subject but I still can't grasp how to use them properly. Can someone explain to me some rules or ways to know how to use them right? Sometimes I do translations in English or write short stories and whenever it comes to this, I'm not sure if I write them correctly, I just write them how I feel it sounds right to me. "Him and I", "me and him", both sound well to me but, so how should I decide what to use?

Recently I had to translate something from Japanese and it was just this, no verb whatsoever, just 2 pronouns and the coordinating conjunction "and".

Comment: Alice see [this answer on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me/358552#358552) for a rather more complete answer than you'll likely to find anywhere else. It discusses, for example, the "rule" or method suggested by @Mitch

Answer (score 1):

Take them one at a time. Then you will see how to put them together.

- **He** went to the cinema.
- **I** went to the cinema.

Becomes:

- **He and I** went to the cinema.

Or:

- **We** went to the cinema.

And:

- She gave **him** a cinema ticket.
- She gave **me** a cinema ticket.

Becomes:

- She gave **him and me** cinema tickets.

Or:

- She gave **us** cinema tickets.

Comment: Yes, I understand it this way, but I was wondering which version to use better, like how I mentioned that I had to translate a title. I actually found a book called "He and I" (by Gabrielle Bossis) and was wondering if "Me and Him" would have also been good or not. Let's say that I want to write a short story, and I have one character that says "He and I, we are quite similar in some ways, for example...".  If I were to replace with "Me and him", would it be wrong? And why? Or what about "Him and I"? 

They all sound good to me, but I would like to hear more explanation.

Comment: To use them properly, you shouldn't combine the subject form with the object form. If you want to break the rule for effect, that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will read that post and hopefully I can get a better understanding! I only read a little, but wow, I wasn't taught so in depth like that during my school years.